# Blank space in ggbarplot where data is missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Looking for a way to keep all bars the same width and leave a blank space where data is missing. Any ideas how to make that work?

```
p = ggbarplot(avg_neighb_ct, x = "First.Object.cellType", y = "count", 
              fill = "data", merge = TRUE, add = "mean_se", width = 0.75) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16)) +
  ylab("Count")
p
```

[image]

** EDIT **

Have added

`position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")`

and now my error bars are off

[image]

Comment: Try adding `position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")` to the call to `ggbarplot`

Comment: Thanks @Peter, have added that and it works but now my error bars are off centre :(

Comment: Have updated the answer, as it turns out `position_dodge(preserve = "single")` does the trick. Next time consider a reproducible question to allow realistic testing of potential solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")` to the call to `ggbarplot`

In the absence of reproducible question, adaptation of an example from the  package documentation demonstrates this:

```r
library(ggpubr)

df3 <- ToothGrowth[!(ToothGrowth$dose == 1 & ToothGrowth$sup == "VC"), ]


ggbarplot(df3, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "supp",
          add = "mean_se", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
          position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>